# Can someone help me with a dropdown menu in my code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a dropdown in some of my links like, Klachten and Specialisaties.

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a> <a class="brand" href="index.html"><span class="color-highlight"><img src="img/logo.png"></span></a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="klachten.html">Klachten</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mensendieck</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Specialisaties</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">De Praktijk</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `select` tag :

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

-> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Or you can use bootstrap :

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

-> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h